# How do i resolve the XamlParserException in WPF

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

i'm getting a XamlParserException when I try to load application. this exception is not consistent.

please help me in this.

Here is the stacktrace of the exception.

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: 'System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension' の値の指定時に例外がスローされました。 ---> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: インデックスが範囲を超えています。負でない値で、コレクションのサイズよりも小さくなければなりません。
パラメーター名: index
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.SetupFrames(BitmapDecoder decoder, ReadOnlyCollection`1 frames)
   at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.Initialize(BitmapDecoder decoder)
   at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapDecoder..ctor(SafeMILHandle decoderHandle, BitmapDecoder decoder, Uri baseUri, Uri uri, Stream stream, BitmapCreateOptions createOptions, BitmapCacheOption cacheOption, Boolean insertInDecoderCache, Boolean isOriginalWritable, Stream uriStream, UnmanagedMemoryStream unmanagedMemoryStream, SafeFileHandle safeFilehandle)
   at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.PngBitmapDecoder..ctor(SafeMILHandle decoderHandle, BitmapDecoder decoder, Uri baseUri, Uri uri, Stream stream, BitmapCreateOptions createOptions, BitmapCacheOption cacheOption, Boolean insertInDecoderCache, Boolean originalWritable, Stream uriStream, UnmanagedMemoryStream unmanagedMemoryStream, SafeFileHandle safeFilehandle)
   at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.CreateFromUriOrStream(Uri baseUri, Uri uri, Stream stream, BitmapCreateOptions createOptions, BitmapCacheOption cacheOption, RequestCachePolicy uriCachePolicy, Boolean insertInDecoderCache)
   at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrame.CreateFromUriOrStream(Uri baseUri, Uri uri, Stream stream, BitmapCreateOptions createOptions, BitmapCacheOption cacheOption, RequestCachePolicy uriCachePolicy)
   at System.Windows.Media.ImageSourceConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)
   at System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension.ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.CallProvideValue(MarkupExtension me, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   --- 内部例外スタック トレースの終わり ---
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
   at PenSoft.PrintSubmenuControl.InitializeComponent()
   at PenSoft.PrintSubmenuControl..ctor(MainWindow parent)
   at PenSoft.PrintSubmenuControl..ctor(PrintEventArgs args, MainWindow parent)
   at PenSoft.MainWindow.CreatePrintControl(Int32 id)
   at PenSoft.MainWindow.CreateSubmenuControl(Squaremenu squareMenu, SubSquareMenu submenuType)
   at PenSoft.ClassicMenuControl.InitLargeClassicMenu()
   at PenSoft.MainWindow.Window_Loaded(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.BroadcastEventHelper.BroadcastEvent(DependencyObject root, RoutedEvent routedEvent)
   at System.Windows.BroadcastEventHelper.BroadcastLoadedEvent(Object root)
   at MS.Internal.LoadedOrUnloadedOperation.DoWork()
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireLoadedPendingCallbacks()
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireInvokeOnRenderCallbacks()
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandlerCore(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandler(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.Resize(ICompositionTarget resizedCompositionTarget)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.OnResize()
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.HandleMessage(WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.HwndTargetFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
```

any answers will be appreciated.

THANKS,
Harish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `XamlParseException` often wraps another Exception, caused by an illegal operation in the XAML. In this case, it's an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.
It's message translates to "Index was out of range. Non-negative value, must be less than the size of the collection".

The stack trace points to `System.Collections.Generic.List1.get_Item(Int32 index)`. So somewhere in your XAML, you're referencing a List with an illegal index.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at exception type : TypeConverterMarkupExtension, you are passing invalid value in your xaml.
Not possible to tell without looking at code, would help if you can share your xaml (which you think is causing this exception.

But, to give idea, this would throw similar exception:

```
...resource
<Color x:Key="ColorResource">Red</Color>
...
<Button Background="{StaticResource ColorResource}" />
//Would throw run-time exception because background expects Brush (and resource is color here)
```